# I am new and just installed Python3.7.4 on Windows 10 and tried to check pip -v in cmd but got this error. OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor[1]

Tags: python, django, cmd, pip, jupyter-notebook

I am using Windows 10 and just installed Python3.7.4 but when I run `pip -v` in cmd, it gives me an error

```
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor[1]
```

I also installed conda and run anaconda-navgator but got the exact same error. I am stuck

Comment: Can you successfully run `pip` alone?

Comment: No I can't. gives me the same error message.. frozen importlib._boostrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first make sure Python path variable properly integrated, Then try again...

You can also view docs for clear concept [link](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)

or reinstall python with follow [link](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html).

Comment: I have tried reinstalling same thing.  >>>File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor<<< this is what I am getting when I run any command having pip.